# How to remove more than one dot (.) from text?

Tags: c#, regex

How to remove more than one dot (.) from text ?

for example:

```
123..45  = 123.45
10.20.30 = 10.2030
12.34    = 12.34
12..     = 12
123...45 = 123.45
```

how to do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything so far?  it seems you know it's doable with a regex, so what is your approach?

Comment: Your 4th example (12.. = 12) seems to run counter to what you asked. Wouldn't it be 12.. = 12.   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to use regex, you can achieve what you need in this way:

```
 string s = "10.20.30";
        int n;
        if( (n=s.IndexOf('.')) != -1 )
            s = string.Concat(s.Substring(0,n+1),s.Substring(n+1).Replace(".",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace("Yourstring", "[.]{2,}",".");
```

Comment: This would only remove second "." from consecutive "." groups. For instance 1..2..3 would give 1.2.3

Comment: @Wowa: please elaborate on your code, showing how it solves the problem - this will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
...
string s = "10.20.30";
while (s.Count( c => c == '.') > 1)
    s = s.Remove( s.LastIndexOf('.'),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using [this overload of `Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx), the trick here is to match everything after the first `.`, by using a look-behind group [ `(?<=` ] then to use a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) to clean that [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx).

```
Regex.Replace(
    "127.0.8", //input string
    @"(?<=\.).*", //match everything after 1st "."
    m => m.Value.Replace(".",string.Empty)) //return value of match without "."
```